# Read timeout error calling a third party REST API

Tags: callout

I am getting Read timeout error while calling a third party REST API.

Can I catch it using try catch block? Or it is not catchable like other Limit Exceptions. Please explain.

Comment: did you try to catch it and couldn't?

Comment: I tried but this error occurs time to time and i am calling third party REST API. So i don't have much control over it.

Comment: can you paste some code?

Comment: Try setting the timeout to 60 secs, req.setTimeout(60000);

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can catch the `CalloutException`; from [the Apex Web Services and Callouts wiki article](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts#HTTP_Code_Sample):

```
try {
    //Execute web service call here     
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);  

    //Helpful debug messages
    System.debug(res.toString());
    System.debug('STATUS:'+res.getStatus());
    System.debug('STATUS_CODE:'+res.getStatusCode());       
} catch(System.CalloutException e) {
    //Exception handling goes here.... retry the call, whatever
}
```

As [logontokartik](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/324/logontokartik) mentions in the comment above, you can also set the timeout on the callout:

```
req.setTimeout(60000); // timeout in milliseconds - this is one minute
```

The default timeout is 10 seconds. The minimum is 1 millisecond and the maximum is 120 seconds.