# Loading Tasks using REST API returns no result, but second try returns a page of Tasks

Tags: soql, rest-api

Sometimes I experience weird issue when loading Tasks over REST API using simple `SELECT Id, ... FROM Task` SOQL query take quite some time and then returns with nothing, but on the second try it returns page of Tasks.

I am using [restforce](https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce) gem to access REST API. I tried it using both default Net::HTTP and Typhoeus adapters, with the similar result.

Any ideas why that happens and how to overcome this?

---

**UPDATE 10 Oct 2013** Looks like this happens exactly 2 minutes after starting an API request independent of timeout settings I set on HTTP client. Looks like Salesforce has a maximum of 2 minutes for any SOQL query. If it takes more than 2 minutes to get the result, it will just kill the request. I haven't found any direct explanation/documentation on that, but I've seen mentions of 2 minutes maximum in similar contexts:

1. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/1725/64
2. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_analytics/salesforce_analytics_rest_api.pdf
3. http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/APIs-and-Integration/REST-API-gt-SOQL-QUERY-TIMEOUT-Issue/td-p/409511
4. http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/Query-Timeout-vs-Network-Timeout/td-p/7280
5. http://community.cazoomi.com/cazoomi/topics/error_code_query_timeout -- apparently one can ask SF reps to lift up this timeout setting

Comment: sounds like in the first attempt something is timing out and the error is getting ignored.

Comment: I agree, I just hoped someone already experienced that and knows the reason. But, looks like I have to dive deeper into this and see if this is something that breaks on client side, or actually SF API breaks a long connection like that

Comment: the 2 minute query timeout should return a specific error, it doesn't just kill the connection

Comment: That's true, but i suspect ruby http client library doesn't handle that correctly.